# How to print the barcode using Epson

Tags: python, epson

I want to print a barcode using epson printer in python i didn't get any error but i got the output is another format not in barcode can any one please help me

```
from escpos import printer
Epson = printer.Usb(0x154f,0x154f,0,0x81,0x02)
Epson.barcode('1324354657687', 'EAN13', 64, 2, '', '')
Epson.cut()
```

Comment: So what's the format? Have you tried `help(Epson.barcode)` to see the internal documentation?

Comment: p.barcode('string, 'type', height, width, 'font type', 'fun type')

Comment: when i run the code i got the output in another format

Comment: What's the type of the other format? Can you do a `print (type(Epson.barcode('1324354657687', 'EAN13', 64, 2, '', ''))`?

Comment: i got <type 'NoneType'>

Comment: please guide me how to print barcode i got the non type here in google also i found these examples only.

Comment: NoneType means it doesn't exist. Something is wrong with your code if it is NoneType. Check your docs and make sure your inputs/arguments/parameters are correct first.

Comment: i saw many examples in google but syntax format is correct